# parent vs parents, which is the correct word to use?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, grammatical-number

i would like to know which of these is exactly correct or is both allowed ? i see people use **parent** and also as **parents** in day to day communication.

Comment: *parent* is singular and *parents* is plural. If you only have one parent, then you "love your parent" (hopefully), and if you have two parents, then you "love your parents". Is this what you meant? Both are proper words in English. Here is the definition of *parent*: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides the singular/plural difference there's always some confusion as to attributive forms, e.g., *parent meeting* vs. *parents meeting* or *parent's meeting* vs. *parents' meeting*.

Oftentimes, when you're using it in this sense, it's more idiomatic (I don't know about 'correct' since it really should be with an apostrophe) to say *parent meeting*. You see it used this way in things like the movie *The Parent Trap*. If, however, you're just saying something like 'his parents' car,' you would obviously use the normal rules for the possessive. The difference is that a *parent meeting* is not literally 'a meeting of/owned by the parents' whereas *his parents' car* is exactly 'the car of his parents.'

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parent

Comment: I doubt if "parent meeting" is grammatically correct because you cannot have 2 nouns back to back.

Answer (score 7):

A parent could be a divorced mom or dad that is single and parents are a mom and a dad. so pretty much **parents is plural for parent**.